# msdropdown: styling certain options differently from the others?

Tags: javascript, msdropdown

I am creating the msdropdown from HTML, that is my code is like:

```
<select id="ex">
<option value="...">...</option>
..etc
</select>
..
$("#ex").msDropdown();
```

I want to have some of the options styled differently from the others (different background color and font color), and for that I tried changing the class of the options I want styled differently, that is, `<option class="something".. >` but msdropdown doesn't "take" this class when it creates its own elements. (I also tried `<option data-className="... >` but that doesn't seem to do the trick either)